# Resizing an existing linux partition during Ubuntu install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, installation

I have Fedora Core 10 installed on a PC, occupying the whole disk (no free space). I want to add Ubuntu 10.04 desktop edition.

Does Ubuntu 10.04 allow you to resize existing partitions during the installation process in order to free up some space for the Ubuntu installation? Without losing or trashing existing data, obviously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it allows. Just use `gparted` (open a Terminal during the live session, type: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted` . After that, `sudo gparted` . Do the work, exit from it, start the install tool.) for that or the installation utility.